# how to select element depend on text content in using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

the source xml is like:

```
<source>
    <idset>
        1,2,4
    </ideset>
    <c id = "1">aaa</c>
    <c id = "2">bbb</c>
    <c id = "3">ccc</c>
    <c id = "4">ddd</c>
</source>
```

use the idset content "1,2,4" to generate new xml, like this:

```
<result>
    aaabbbddd
</result>
```

i think it should use the text "1,2,4" as a parameter, but i dont know how to do this

Comment: Isn't this what you're trying to do in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827744/how-to-translate-xml-using-xslt-with-complex-rules ?

Answer (score 0):

Using XSLT 2.0 based on your previous question...

**Input XML**

```
<source>
    <idset>
        1,2,4
    </ideset>
    <c id = "1">aaa</c>
    <c id = "2">bbb</c>
    <c id = "3">ccc</c>
    <c id = "4">ddd</c>
</source>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/source">
        <result>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="c[@id=tokenize(normalize-space(current()/idset),',')]/text()"/>            
        </result>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<result>aaabbbddd</result>
```

Answer (score 0):

**An XSLT 1.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <result>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="c"/>
  </result>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match=
 "c[not(contains(concat(',', normalize-space(/*/idset), ','),
                 concat(',', @id, ',')
                 )
        )
    ]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<source>
    <idset>
    1,2,4
    </idset>
    <c id = "1">aaa</c>
    <c id = "2">bbb</c>
    <c id = "3">ccc</c>
    <c id = "4">ddd</c>
</source>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<result>aaabbbddd</result>
```